# The relationship between minimum of summation and the summation of minimum

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I would like to investigate the relationship between:

$\min\{f(x) + g(x)\}$ and $\min\{f(x)\} + \min\{g(x)\}$

I think that it is fundamental and of course there exists a theorem or a lemma handling this relationship but I cannot find out.

My try: I made a toy example:
$f(x) = x^2 - 2x - 3$ and $g(x) = x^2 + 2x -3$. Then  $\min\{f(x) + g(x)\} = -6$ and $\min\{f(x)\} + \min\{g(x)\} = -8$. It means that  $\min\{f(x) + g(x)\}\geq \min\{f(x)\} + \min\{g(x)\}$

Answer (score 5):

For each $x$, $f(x) \ge \min\{f(x)\}$ and $g(x) \ge \min\{g(x)\}$ so $$f(x) + g(x) \ge \min\{f(x)\} + \min \{g(x)\}$$
Therefore $$\min \{f(x) + g(x)\} \ge \min\{f(x)\} + \min \{g(x)\}$$

Comment: Could you please tell me the conditions to obtain $\min \{f(x) + g(x)\} = \min\{f(x)\} + \min\{ g(x) \}$?

Comment: Necessary and sufficient (assuming these minima exist) is that there is an $x$ that minimizes both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: I don't quite follow the conclusion you made. Can you please elaborate? Are you applying the minimum on both sides of the equality f(x) + g(x) >= min(f(x)) + min(g(x))?

Comment: If $A(x) \ge B$ for every $x$, then $\min \left\{A(x)\right\} \ge B$.