# Proof: Sum of minimum of two functions vs minimum of sum of functions

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima, summation-method

I wonder whether the following is true:

$$\min\big\{f_1(x),g_1(x)\big\} + \min\big\{f_2(x),g_2(x)\big\}\le \min\big\{f_1(x)+f_2(x),~g_1(x) + g_2(x)\big\}.$$

I already know [how to prove that:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033178/the-relationship-between-minimum-of-summation-and-the-summation-of-minimum)

$$\min\{f(x)\}+\min\{g(x)\} \le \min\{f(x)+g(x)\},$$

but I cannot proceed with the handling of the minimum of two functions.

Comment: Assume the four cases and see the result.

Comment: Oh I see... I can simply assume values for x. I was thinking too complicated.

Comment: Not for x, assume the values for fs and the gs.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** Assuming $f_1(x) \ge g_1(x)$ and $f_2(x) \ge g_2(x)$:
$$g_1(x) + g_2(x) \le g_1(x) + g_2(x)~\checkmark$$ as $f_1(x)+f_2(x) \ge g_1(x)+g_2(x)$.

**Case 2:** Assuming $f_1(x) \ge g_1(x)$ and $f_2(x) \le g_2(x)$:
$$g_1(x) + f_2(x) \le \min\big\{f_1(x)+f_2(x),~g_1(x) + g_2(x)\big\}$$
The right side of the above equation is minimal in the following cases $f_1(x) = g_1(x)$ or $f_2(x) = g_2(x)$. Thus:
$$g_1(x) + f_2(x) \le g_1(x) + f_2(x)~\checkmark$$
Cases 3 and 4 are done analogue.

Comment: Notice that the left-hand side in your inequality is less than $f_1(x)+f_2(x)$ and less than $g_1(x)+g_2(x)$. Hence the left-hand side is less than the minimum of both.